# how to extract data from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hello Stack Overflow i hope you are well today;

So i am using jQuery to append a form with more input fields;
The Session is storing the data as an Array for the key: Children.

I would like to know show the user the data in that array how would this be done?

jQuery that adds the input fields (some pages previous)

```
 $('.children-main-add').click(function(){
    var attrName = $(this).attr('name');
    var count = $(this).attr('count');
    $(this).attr('count', (parseInt(count)+1))
    var input = $('<input />');
    input.attr('type','text')
    input.attr('name',attrName+"["+count+"]" ) 
    $('.children-main').append($('<li />').append(input));
    $('#content li').removeClass('alt');
    $('#content li:odd').addClass('alt');
    $(this).val('Add Another Child');
})
```

The data from the session : Key: children / Value: Array

If i was not clear on something please let me know !

I thank you in advance for your help

Comment: i have tried the usual method `<?php if(isset($_SESSION['children'])) { echo $_SESSION['children']; } ?>`

Comment: use this `print_r($_SESSION['children']);`  Can you show any example with data.

Comment: please use `print_r` for echoing arrays to the screen, and if it doesnt work use `var_dump` so we can better understand what the array holds

Comment: @Gaurav thanks that worked but how would i show it in an eligible format atm it displays like this: `Array ( [0] => Julia Roberts [1] => Zaraki Akram [2] => Simon Evans Smith )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to show them as an continue string

use `impode(',' , $_SESSION['children']);`

Or

```
if(isset($_SESSION['children']) && is_array($_SESSION['children']))
{
    foreach($_SESSION['children'] as $child)
    {
      echo $child."<br />";  
      // some other html
    }
}
```

Comment: i actually want to show them seperately i.e.

Julia Roberts <br /> Zaraki Akram <br /> Simon Evans Smith

So each on a new line